# SQL - Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, pls-00103

I'm trying to create a procedure. When I run my code I get the error:

```
21/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one
         of the following:
         ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
         raise return select update while with <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
         continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
         savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

Perhaps it has to do with my `BEGIN` and `END` statements? I'm new to SQL and haven't been able to figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE inserttocasting(idofmovie  IN casting.movieid%TYPE,
                                            idofactor  IN casting.actorid%TYPE,
                                            newordinal IN casting.ordinal%TYPE)
IS
  identical_ordinal EXCEPTION;
  too_many_movies EXCEPTION;
BEGIN

  SELECT cast_year(idofmovie) INTO v_year FROM dual;

  IF ordinal_count(newordinal, idofmovie) >= 1 THEN
    RAISE identical_ordinal;
  ELSIF cast_count(v_year, idofactor) >= 3 THEN
    RAISE too_many_movies;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO casting (movieid, actorid, ordinal)
    VALUES (idofmovie, idofactor, newordinal);
  END IF;

  EXCEPTION WHEN identical_ordinal THEN
    dbms_output.PUT_LINE('Ordinal already exists for this film!');

  EXCEPTION WHEN too_many_movies THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This actor has already been cast in more than three movies this year.');
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Here is the code for the functions being used if necessary:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ordinal_count(
newordinal IN CASTING.ORDINAL%TYPE, idofmovie IN CASTING.MOVIEID%TYPE
) RETURN NUMBER AS 
p_ordinal_number NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(ACTORID)
INTO p_ordinal_number
FROM CASTING
WHERE ORDINAL = newordinal
AND MOVIEID = idofmovie;
RETURN p_ordinal_number;
END ordinal_count;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cast_year(idofmovie IN CASTING.MOVIEID%TYPE
) RETURN NUMBER AS 
v_year NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT YEAR
INTO v_year
FROM MOVIE
WHERE MOVIEID = idofmovie;
RETURN v_year;
END cast_year;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cast_count(v_year IN MOVIE.YEAR%TYPE, idofactor IN CASTING.ACTORID%TYPE
) RETURN NUMBER AS 
v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(v_year)
INTO v_count
FROM CASTING
WHERE ACTORID = idofactor;
RETURN v_count;
END cast_count;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your first procedure to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertToCasting(
  idofmovie IN CASTING.MOVIEID%TYPE,
  idofactor IN CASTING.ACTORID%TYPE,
  newordinal IN CASTING.ORDINAL%TYPE)
IS
  identical_ordinal EXCEPTION;
  too_many_movies EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT cast_year(idofmovie)
    INTO v_year
    FROM dual;

  IF ordinal_count(newordinal, idofmovie) >= 1 THEN
    RAISE identical_ordinal;
  ELSIF cast_count(v_year, idofactor) >= 3 THEN
    RAISE too_many_movies;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO CASTING (MOVIEID, ACTORID, ORDINAL)
      VALUES (idofmovie, idofactor, newordinal);

    COMMIT;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN identical_ordinal THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Ordinal already exists for this film!');
  WHEN too_many_movies THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This actor has already been cast in more than three movies this year.');
END;
```

You can put multiple WHEN blocks in a single EXCEPTION handler. Also, you had the COMMIT statement at the end of the `WHEN too_many_movies...` handler, when I suspect you wanted it to follow the INSERT. The way it was positioned it would only have executed if the `too_many_movies` handler was entered, which didn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! This looks much better, except I now receive the error:

10/6     PLS-00201: identifier 'V_YEAR' must be declared

Am I not storing my function into v_year properly under the BEGIN statement?

Comment: You don't have a variable named `v_year` declared in your `insertToCasting` procedure. Try adding one in the declarations section. In addition, now that I look at it, I suggest replacing `SELECT cast_year(idofmovie) INTO v_year FROM dual` with `v_year := cast_year(idofmovie)` which is both shorter and easier to understand.